# Apex flow create record

Tags: visual-workflow, record

I have a problem. If we create a record in salesforce flow (for example 'quote' object) and if we choose the option 'use all values from a record' than we have a variable that will contain that created record. But the problem is I don't know how to get the id of this newly created record. So I just have the variable with the whole record but not the variable with the id of this record.   [image]

For example, if I create a record the same way but with the option 'use separate resources and literal values' than I suddenly have the opportunity to add the variable that will contain the newly created record. So the point is why I don't have this opportunity when I create record with the option 'Use all values from a record'? Because that would be very useful. Or maybe there is some other way how I could retrieve the id of the record that was created with the option 'Use all values from a record'? [image] [image]

Here is my flow: I have a 'Get Records' action which gives me the 'Get_quote' variable which stores the record that I get from my database. Then I have a 'Create Records' action in which I take that record that I got through Get Records action and then I create a new cloned record and I have a variable 'Create_quote' which stores the newly created record. [image]
____________________________Here there is this variable
[image]

And here I try to get the id of that 'Create_quote' variable and I have an error.
[image]

Comment: And did you check the record.Id value after the create record block as it is stated in your first screenshot?

Comment: Salesforce does not allow to get the id of that record by writing record.id. I just have the whole variable 'record' that holds the new record, but no ability to get any separate field from that record (For example when I use assignment I cannot pick any field from that record like (record.id, record.name, ect), I can only put the whole record at once). Either the whole record or nothing while I need only the ID of that record.

Comment: no it is possible just like this `{!record.Id}`

Comment: I've tried using variable record's ID — it returns URL of the original record for some reason, even though I never assigned anything to it…

Answer (score 0):

In the first assignment i assign subject to new task record, then i create it, and then in the second assignment i can read the `{!asd.id}`.

[image]

[image]

See, you can read the id as this.

[image]

This is specifically the quote id field listed.

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand, asd - is the initial object on base of which you create clone object. Then you assign the id of that initial object to a variable, but can you assign the id of a newly created object to a variable? The 'Create records' action should create a variable called 'create' or something according to your flow. So, can you retrieve the id from that variable?

Comment: No asd is a completely new object which i created inside the flow in the Create block. After the creation you can read the id as i stated.

Comment: Sorry man I still dont get it. In your answer you say that you create a new record using values that are stored in 'asd'. If so, then from where 'asd' comes from?

Comment: You just create new record variable and in assign you assign there some fields, e.g. to task record assign subject and then create this record with the create records

Comment: I updated My question and added pictures of my flow. What would you recommend me to do in my case?

Comment: First, in the create action there is specifically said that you have to make sure that the variable does not contain Id field, which in your case it does as you queried the whole record. So i think that event this part will not work.
Second, even in this case you can simply get to the Id field, but the label of the id field on quote is Quote Id, so try that pls.

Comment: I added screen to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this:

SFDC Flow offers two options for creating a single record

- From a record variable (in which case, after creation, the record variable's Id field will have a value) -- this is your first screen shot
- From an enumerated set of fields (in which case, you provide a text variable to hold the Id after insert) - this is your second screen shot

Record variables are SObjects and behave the way they do with Apex DML. When you insert an Sobject, the result of the insert DML updates the Sobject (record) variable with the Id.  You can't insert an Sobject if the Id field is populated.